# How can I JQ transform array into a different array, joint with other data?

Tags: jq, jqtransform

I need to transform this:

```
{"input":{"text":"HI"},"output":{"text":["OK1","TWO"]}}
```

Into this:

```
{
  "localDB": [
    {
      "tableName": "Default",
      "mode": "append",
      "data": [
        {
          "time": "1511281401.991815",
          "message": "HI",
          "from": "me"
        },
        {
          "time": "1511281401.991837",
          "message": "OK1"
          "from": "bot"
        }
        {
          "time": "1511281401.991847",
          "message": "TWO"
          "from": "bot"
}
]}]}
```

Is it possible at all?

Key issue here is that number of "records" in the localDB **should vary depending on** the number of entries in .output.text node. There could be just one text, or three or more.

I tried with this, but it is not quite working:

```
{
 "localDB" : [{
   "tableName": "Default",
   "mode": "append",
   "data": [
     {"time" : now|tostring, "message" : .input.text, "from" : "me"},
     {"time" : now|tostring, "message" :.output.text, "from" : "bot"}
  ]
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close.  You just need to use `.output.text[]` and take advantage of how [Object Construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) behaves when a member expression returns multiple results. Try this:

```
{
 "localDB" : [{
   "tableName": "Default",
   "mode": "append",
   "data": [
     {"time" : now|tostring, "message" : .input.text,   "from" : "me"},
     {"time" : now|tostring, "message" :.output.text[], "from" : "bot"}
  ]
 }]
}
```

Sample Output

```
{
  "localDB": [
    {
      "tableName": "Default",
      "mode": "append",
      "data": [
        {
          "time": "1511283566.11608",
          "message": "HI",
          "from": "me"
        },
        {
          "time": "1511283566.116094",
          "message": "OK1",
          "from": "bot"
        },
        {
          "time": "1511283566.116094",
          "message": "TWO",
          "from": "bot"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Bi8IwEIXv/oow57TgtUfxsIugF8FD6WHcRqmkmdpOUaj562anqYoezSGPvBe@mXc6hwEq1/QM2QBsrqLw8wteA/X8YeewWc1Bw3a3gcL72S0oOcNsvBVY@kO7XIDKVP7wxGXcW7PG2kCmYGkO2FsG/YprKmOCTWNc@RaUyChB/jRkDnAlGME7utyYOm4rd9TCMF2Hx5iksUg6rqtHyqGlevTljxT6ipVO7SMrL/Qba08M/sEqJvWT@hDu1HBFrgtJ4nprk7iQPFq8JBPxHw)

---

Here is a filter which uses a `settime` function to assign different times to the rows:

```
def settime: reduce range(length) as $i (.; .[$i].time = (now + $i|tostring));
{
 "localDB" : [{
   "tableName": "Default",
   "mode": "append",
   "data": [
     {"message" : .input.text,   "from" : "me"},
     {"message" :.output.text[], "from" : "bot"}
   ] | settime
 }]
}
```

Sample Output

```
{
  "localDB": [
    {
      "tableName": "Default",
      "mode": "append",
      "data": [
        {
          "message": "HI",
          "from": "me",
          "time": "1511285948.684203"
        },
        {
          "message": "OK1",
          "from": "bot",
          "time": "1511285949.684243"
        },
        {
          "message": "TWO",
          "from": "bot",
          "time": "1511285950.684261"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNa4QwEL3vrxiGPSjVQK8uvZQ9tBS6l0IP4iG7ztqUmFgzsgXNX6@NWssWmkOGeR8zyXv/GHtUpukYsx6ZPkPFh0f0CdqO/8A5Hp5uMcGX1wMW3m@GEcIp6QyOmFVNGbRUdieCVpqKIk2m4rcYpIOtgkjsQORbVYhJCncQGXuBm0ANbB23ylRxvNtMI/v5BtT2JPX@HiGD/AcLKMujpmdZE2aAezrLTjMmv3Rty5mRTUOmvCJKyTIQ@QqEPViTc7KiaYOYQxDTV5NJfm5tPeFBE8L43ySWiGZTXiRXpqNl9KupgGGNaIF8MVc/jl@2YWWNG9PUdFqn8yNC08pLugz/Bg)

Comment: Wow, it works very good. Except for one thing: those records are getting exactly the same timestamp. I'm using timestamp for sorting, so on some devices it breaks the order. Any suggestion on how to solve this? I tried "time" : (now+1)|tostring, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the time to come from the input?

Comment: Not really. The only last problem now is to differentiate between two output messages. Input is clearly earlier and it is visible in your Sample Output. Is there a way to add a counter and concatenate it with "time" value, still within this operation?

Comment: I've added a second example showing how you could use a function to set a different time on each row.